# A thread calling Remote service waits for method to finish?

Tags: java, android, service, remote-access, remoteobject

I have made a simple test of calling a remote service (on a different process) and I found something very suprising.

Suppose we have two processes:
**Process-A with Thread-A**
and
**Process-B**.

If process A is runnign Thread-A and Thread-A calls a remote void method using IPC - AIDL.
What will happen is:
Process-B will have one of its Binder Threads run the method called.
During this time Thread-A in Process-A will wait.
Only after the Binder thread in Process-B will finish the method call, Thread A will be notified and resume its work.

**My question:**
Is this a standard behavior?
And if so, why is it like that? Thread-A should not wait if its a void method. (is "oneway" related to it?)

**My code:**

**In Process A:**

```
Log.d("Text", "Lior: Client: Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Passing parcelableClass:     parcelableClass.hashCode: " + parcelableClass.hashCode());
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

_iRemoteServiceBinder.passObject(parcelableClass);

}
Log.d("Text", "Lior: Client: Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Passed parcelableClass:     parcelableClass.hashCode: " + parcelableClass.hashCode());
```

**In Process B:**

```
private final IRemoteServicePassObject.Stub _binder = new IRemoteServicePassObject.Stub() {

    @Override
    public void passObject(ParcelableClass parcelableClass)
            throws RemoteException {

        Log.d("Text", "Lior: Service: got pacelableClass: a: " + parcelableClass.getA() + 
                " b: " + parcelableClass.getB() + 
                " s: " + parcelableClass.getS() + " hashCode: " + parcelableClass.hashCode()
                + " Running thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        try {

            Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("Text", "Lior: Service: Finished: "
                + " Running thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

The result I am getting:

> 01-15 19:52:03.292: D/Text(22792): Lior: Client: Thread: main Passing
>   parcelableClass: parcelableClass.hashCode: 1096225792 01-15
>   19:52:03.297: D/Text(23014): Lior: Service: got pacelableClass: a: 1
>   b: 2 s: String hashCode: 1096136272 Running thread: Binder Thread #2
>   01-15 19:52:08.302: D/Text(23014): Lior: Service: Finished:  Running
>   thread: Binder Thread #2 01-15 19:52:08.312: D/Text(23014): Lior:
>   Service: running new thread: LiorThread 01-15 19:52:10.342:
>   D/Text(22792): Lior: Client: Thread: main Passed parcelableClass:
>   parcelableClass.hashCode: 1096225792

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: added. I am programming for android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Any thread calling Remote method is waiting until the method is finished in the remote process.
In order to make the call asynchronous - we need to define the AIDL as oneway.
for example:
    oneway interface IRemoteServiceOnewayAIDL {